# How to center merged cells vertically in a table and stretch the merged border to cover all of the cell?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, border, cell

I am using the code:

```
\definecolor{atlas}{RGB}{11,128,195}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| l | C{2cm} | C{4cm} | C{5cm} |}
\hline
\rowcolor{atlas} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{CANbus}} & \textbf{Port} & \textbf{Computer} & \textbf{Project} \\
\hline
\hline
EI\textunderscore A\textunderscore top & can1 & PC4 & PROJ4 \\
\cline{1-2}
EI\textunderscore A\textunderscore bottom & can0 &  \\
\hline
EI\textunderscore C\textunderscore top & can0 & PC5 & PROJ5 \\
\cline{1-2}
EI\textunderscore C\textunderscore bottom & can1 &  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{All communication parts of the CANbuses.}
\end{table}
```

Which gives the output:
[image]

As you can see, the Computer and Project rows are not centered vertically and moreover, the right border in the merged cells in missing half of its length. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with `multirow`, and completing the number of empty cells ;

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{float}
    \definecolor{atlas}{RGB}{11,128,195}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| l | C{2cm} | C{4cm} | C{5cm} |}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{atlas} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{CANbus}} & \textbf{Port} & \textbf{Computer} & \textbf{Project} \\
    \hline
    \hline
    EI\textunderscore A\textunderscore top & can1 & \multirow{2}{=}{\centering PC4} & \multirow{2}{=}{\centering PROJ4} \\
    \cline{1-2}
    EI\textunderscore A\textunderscore bottom & can0 & & \\
    \hline
    EI\textunderscore C\textunderscore top & can0 & \multirow{2}{=}{\centering PC5} & \multirow{2}{=}{\centering PROJ5} \\
    \cline{1-2}
    EI\textunderscore C\textunderscore bottom & can1 & & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{All communication parts of the CANbuses.}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]